# Android where to define the fragment tag?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Should the fragment tag be part of fragment or it should be defined in the activity ? Which is the best approach and why ?

In most of the google examples why the fragment tag is defined inside the activity.

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_TAG";
```

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/packages/PrintSpooler/src/com/android/printspooler/ui/PrintActivity.java) is a sample example.

How it works when multiple instances of a single Fragment are added to stack with a parameter tag named testtag". fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_fragment, fragment, "testtag"); If you create multiple instances of same fragment and add them then are you able to get them with out unique tags ?

Comment: A fragment tag is by definition *"part of fragment"*. Try providing examples to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal and Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Did you even open the link? Provide a minimal example in the question differentiating the two cases, instead of providing a large code file to *sift* through.

Comment: @Abbas private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_TAG";           https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/packages/PrintSpooler/src/com/android/printspooler/ui/PrintActivity.java   In this example too the fragment tag is part of the activity and not a public static final string inside the fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127143/discussion-between-nick-and-abbas).

Comment: According to me, a better place to keep the tag is within the fragment itself. But for simple trivial examples, it's OK to put in Activity.

Comment: Thank you Mittal. Is it mentioned any where in the Google documentation or the best practices about this ?

Answer (score 0):

yes the fragment tag is a part of fragment.You can set a Tag during fragment transaction e.g. using `add`, `replace`, or as part of the layout.

Comment: what i should do through this link?

Comment: How it works when multiple instances of a single Fragment are added to stack with a parameter tag named testtag".

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_fragment, fragment, "testtag");
If you create multiple instances of same fragment and add them then are you able to get them with out unique tags ?